# How to add a '+' sign in front of a number in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, substring, concatenation, number-formatting

This program gets the difference of the numbers in the grade lists and pairs them with the respective classes.

```
classlist = ['CLASS1', 'CLASS2', 'CLASS3', 'CLASS4', 'CLASS5', 'CLASS6', 'CLASS7']
gradelist1 = ['91', '--', '95', '0']
gradelist2 = ['90', '80', '98', '96']

def gradeChangeShow():
    difference = []
    gradelist1_change = [g.replace('--', '0.0') for g in gradelist1]
    gradelist2_change = [g.replace('--', '0.0') for g in gradelist2]
    for i in range(len(gradelist1)):
        difference = ["{:.1f}".format(float(a) - float(b)) for a, b in zip(gradelist2_change, gradelist1_change)]
    statement = [f'\n{c.rstrip()}: {d}' for c, d in zip(classlist, difference) if float(d) != 0.0]
    #maybe something here
    comma_delete = ','.join(statement)
    if difference:
        return comma_delete.replace(',', '')
    else:
        return ('\nNo grade changes.')
        
print(gradeChangeShow())
```

My question is, how do I get the output from looking like this:

```
CLASS1: -1.0
CLASS2: 80.0
CLASS3: 3.0
CLASS4: 96.0
```

To this:

```
CLASS1: -1.0
CLASS2: +80.0
CLASS3: +3.0
CLASS4: +96.0
```

I've searched Stack Overflow and the only examples I find are of people adding plus signs to the start of ints. And in my case, I can't add the sign at the beginning of the program either (I don't think) because I subtract the float value of the numbers in the grade lists and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your format string `{:.1f}` with `{:+.1f}`, which always displays the sign.

Comment: just `{:+}` does it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cycling through and making them all strings, and adding a plus sign if the int is positive.

Answer (score 0):

replace the formatting like so: {:+.1f} or concatenate a + like so: '+' + ...